# OOP in Rock, Paper, Scissors program

Tags: python, object-oriented, game, rock-paper-scissors

This is an OOP Rock, Paper, Scissors program I wrote in Python.  I am just learning about using classes and I'd appreciate some advice on improving it.

```
# rock.py
# example of OOP
import random

class Rock:
    def main(self):
        self.Make_players()
        print("Best of Five - Let's play!\n")
        done  = False
        while done == False:
            self.p1.go_player()
            self.p2.go_player()
            print()
            if self.p2.go == self.p1.go:
                print("No winner!\n")
                continue
            else:
                temp = self.check(self.p1, self.p2)
            if temp == False:
                temp = self.check(self.p2, self.p1)
            print(self.message, end = " ")
            print(temp.name + " won this round.")
            temp.scored()
            print(self.p1.name + ": " + str(self.p1.score))
            print(self.p2.name + ": " + str(self.p2.score))
            if self.p1.score == 3:
                self.winner = self.p1
                done = True
            elif self.p2.score == 3:
                self.winner = self.p2
                done = True
            else:
                done = False
                input()
        print("The winner was " + self.winner.name + "!")


def __init__(self):
    print("**** Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!****\n")
    self.winner = False
    self.main()

def Make_players(self):
    temp = (input("What shall we call Player 1? "))
    self.p1 = Player(temp)
    temp = (input("What shall we call Player 2? "))
    self.p2 = Player(temp)

def check(self, p_a, p_b):
    if p_a.go == "rock" and p_b.go == "scissors":
        self.message = "Rock breaks scissors."
        return p_a
    elif p_a.go == "paper" and p_b.go == "rock":
        self.message = "Paper wraps stone."
        return p_a
    elif p_a.go == "scissors" and p_b.go == "paper":
        self.message = "Scissors cut paper."
        return p_a
    else:
        return False

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
        self.score = 0
        self.name = name
        print("Player:", self.name, "created!\n")

    def go_player(self):
        self.go = random.choice(self.choices)
        print(self.name + " chose " + self.go, end = ". ")
        return self.go

    def scored(self):
        self.score += 1

# Main
game = Rock()
```

Answer (score 6):

The best OOP advice I can give for this code is: [stop writing classes](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes).

Ideally, watch the video first (it’s not that long) and come back later. But here’s the gist:

> A class that has only one publicly called method (or less) isn’t a legitimate class. It should be a method.

Consequently, `Rock` shouldn’t be a class. It should be a method.

The rest is detail criticism. Most importantly, [read PEP8 (the Python style guide)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and adhere to it. Notably, this includes naming conventions, and using *meaningful* names.

Next, separate concerns clearly. `go_player` shouldn’t print text, its sole task should be to generate a random game choice. The printing should happen elsewhere.

Similarly (i.e. still a separation-of-concerns problem), neither all possible choices (i.e. `choices`) nor the *current choice* (i.e. `go`) logically belong in the `Player`. They are separate entities.

`self.winner = False` is logically wrong. The variable doesn’t contain a boolean value later on, why does it contain one now? Same goes for `check` – it should return `None`, not `False`.

Next, use a standard entry point. The following is pretty much an established pattern in Python that all code should follow:

```
def main():
    …

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

This way, the code can be executed directly or reused as a module.

And a check like `while done == False` is like fingernails across a blackboard for professional programmers: explicit checks against boolean literals **never** (!) make sense. Use `while not done` instead.

In summary, here’s how I’d do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import random

# The extended, cool rules:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock
CHOICES = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'Spock']

RULES = {
    'rock': {
        'scissors': 'blunts',
        'lizard': 'crushes'},
    'paper': {
        'rock': 'covers',
        'Spock': 'disproves'},
    'scissors': {
        'paper': 'cuts',
        'lizard': 'decapitates'},
    'lizard': {
        'paper': 'eats',
        'Spock': 'poisons'},
    'Spock': {
        'rock': 'vaporizes',
        'scissors': 'smashes'}
}


class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, num):
        name = raw_input('What shall we call player {}? '.format(num))
        return cls(name)

    def go(self):
        return random.choice(CHOICES)

    def scored(self):
        self.score += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def get_winner(players, choices):
    """
    Determine winner of a rock-paper-scissors round.

    Returns a tuple of (winner, winning move) if exists, else None.
    """
    def get_rule(cs):
        return RULES[cs[0]].get(cs[1], None)

    move = get_rule(choices)

    if move is not None:
        winner = players[0]
    else:
        choices = choices[::-1]
        move = get_rule(choices)
        winner = players[1]

    if move is None:
        return None

    return (winner, (choices[0], move, choices[1]))


def game(how_many_rounds):
    if how_many_rounds % 2 == 0:
        raise RuntimeError('Rounds must be an uneven number')

    players = [Player.create(1), Player.create(2)]
    winning_score = how_many_rounds // 2 + 1

    print('Best of {} - let\'s play!\n'.format(how_many_rounds))

    while True:
        choices = [p.go() for p in players]
        for p, c in zip(players, choices):
            print p, c
        win = get_winner(players, choices)

        if win is None:
            print('No winner.\n')
            continue

        winner, move = win
        winner.scored()
        print('{} {} {}. {} won this round.'.format(
                move[0].capitalize(), move[1], move[2], winner))
        for p in players:
            print('{}: {}'.format(p, p.score))

        if winner.score == winning_score:
            break

        raw_input()

    print('The winner was {}!'.format(winner))


def main():
    game(99)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

To be honest, I’m not entirely satisfied with this since I prefer having immutable objects as much as possible, and the player objects here are *not* immutable. In fact, I’d probably get rid of the `Player`s entirely and store the game state inside the game, where it belongs.

(Proper documentation is left as an exercise for the reader. I’ve only documented `get_winner` since it would be incomprehensible without documentation.)

Comment: `score` isn't an attribute on `Player`; you should have a `scoreboard := map(Player, int)` or even `:= Counter(Player)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would change `check` to this

```
def check(self, p_a, p_b):
    messages = {"rock":"Rock breaks scissors.",
                "paper":"Paper wraps stone.",
                "scissors":"Scissors cut paper.",
               }
    if p_a.go == p_b.go:
        return False
    elif p_a.go == "rock" and p_b.go == "scissors":
        self.message = messages[p_a.go]
        return p_a
    elif p_a.go == "paper" and p_b.go == "rock":
        self.message = messages[p_a.go]
        return p_a
    elif p_a.go == "scissors" and p_b.go == "paper":
        self.message = messages[p_a.go]
        return p_a
    else:
        # if moves are not same and player1 couldn't win than it should be
        # player2 who wins that round
        self.message = messages[p_b.go]
        return p_b
```

And the part where you check moves:

```
temp = self.check(self.p1, self.p2)
if not temp: 
    print("No winner!\n")
    continue
```

Edit after antiloquax's comment:

Even it will work that way I don't like it. you can use a class variable `messages = {"rock":"...",}` as I did in `check` method. While printing you just say

```
print(self.messages[temp.go])
```

Comment: Thanks savruk. I was thinking about something like that - but the "else:" here would just return the player without printing the message "Paper wraps stone" etc. I think.

Comment: antiloquax, you are right. I didn't think about it. See my edited answer. As a move can only win against a certain move(rock can only beat scissors, scissors can only beat paper ...), it is easy to use a dictionary to define a message for the move.